# A number theoretic identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $2n+1$ is prime.
The elements of the factor group $G = \mathbb{F}^\times_{2n+1}/\{\pm 1\}$ can be represented by the integers $1,2,\ldots,n$. For every $x \in \mathbb{F}^\times_{2n+1}$, let $x' \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ denote the representative of its image in $G$. For every $\lambda \in\{2,\ldots,n-1\}$, let

$$ S_\lambda = \sum_{a=1}^n |a-(a\lambda)'|, $$

where $|\cdot|$ denotes the usual absolute value. For example, when $n=6$, 
and $\lambda=3$, 
$$ S_3 = |1-3| + |2-6| + |3-4| + |4-1| + |5-2| + |6-5| = 14. $$

Is it true that $S_\lambda = n(n+1)/3$, for every $\lambda \geq 2$?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? It was mentioned in http://www.mathlinks.ro/viewtopic.php?t=125645 , and hipsishopsis has posted a proof. Haven't checked it, however.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unmotivated problem that comes from and is solved elsewhere.

Comment: The link given by darij grinberg to a possible proof by hipsishopsis no longer works.  The question doesn't look bad to me.

Comment: it is true at least up to $2n+1<1000$.

Comment: Do those who voted to close see an easy proof of this?  It seems a remarkable fact to me (if true), but maybe I'm missing something obvious.  The objection that the problem is unmotivated doesn't seem correct to me: if the numbers from $1$ to $m$ are permuted randomly without fixed points, the expected value of $|a-\sigma(a)|$ would be the answer given.  It's not at all clear to me why multiplication by $\lambda$ should always give exactly this answer.

Comment: I agree with @Lucia and I voted to reopen.

Comment: @Lucia: I found the originally linked solution in the internet archive, but I haven't read it: https://web.archive.org/web/20090824064816/http://btw.blobtrox.net/~btw/modabs.pdf

Comment: I suppose that I understand what's written here, but it's written quite badly.  For example, does the expression $a-(a\lambda)'$ live in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $G$?

Comment: @DanielLitt: I updated the text. I hope it is clear now that $a-(a\lambda)'$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, because both $a$ and $(a\lambda)'$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The link by darij grinberg now redirects to http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h125645